# GPO Denied (Security Filter) not applying

Tags: windows-7, windows, group-policy, security-policy

I am having an issue in my company.

I have a GPO, and one group in security filter, lets name it group X. In my delegation, I set the permissions to X (Allow Read and Allow Apply Group Policy).

The user is in the group X, and when I log on the computer, this GPO is denied by the security filter. How can I troubleshoot to identify where it is denying this GPO?

I don't know if this is relevant, but this group X denies another GPO and allows this specific one.

Answer (score 3):

You probably removed Authenticated Users from the Group Policy, if so:

Add Authenticated Users back by using the "Delegation" tab and select "Read" on the role (very important). The Authenticated User should **NOT** be able to "Apply the Group Policy" but just "Read" the group policy (otherwise your filter based on the group membership will not work).

[Since June 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3159398/ms16-072-description-of-the-security-update-for-group-policy-june-14,-2016), the group policies are retrieved with the computer account (including users group policies), so you must allow the computers to read the policy settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[gpresult /scope user /h rsop.html](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733160(v=ws.11).aspx)** to see the user’s RSoP (Resultant Set of Policy), which should provide detail about the security filtering on the GPO in question and why it isn’t applying the way you expect.

Be sure you’ve removed the **Authenticated Users** from the Security Filtering on the Scope tab if you only want your GPO to apply to users in group X; see [this TechNet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759506(v=ws.10).aspx) for more info.